# jQuery/Javascript. Highlighting a certain something when on a certain page and general tips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I am learning jquery/javascript through trial and error by myself with the help of different sites and video tutorials.
I got a gig for a stand-up team.
I made a loader because i want the site to load easily and with no lag, made some fadeIns for certain parts of the page, etc..

I got a problem with the nav bar, the site will have around 6-7 pages and i want to extract the id of every html page the user is on with $("html").attr("id");, put it in a var x and then ask something like if(x="1/2/3/4/5/6") $("header").css("border","blabla"). It seems that the browser has some problems with var x or the = token, i am continuously getting errors regarding those 2. Any ideeas?
Also is it ok if i made something like this for the loader:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loading").delay(2000).fadeOut("fast");


    $("header").hide().delay(2050).fadeIn(500);
    $("footer").hide().delay(2050).fadeIn(500);
    $(".interior").hide().delay(2050).fadeIn(550);
    });
```

This is the part i wanted to use for highlighting a nav buton

```
   *$(document).ready(function(){
        var x = $("html").attr("id");
        if(var = "1") $("#buton1").css("border","2px solid #E80000").css("border-radius","20px");
    });
```

Is it a productive way of working or there are other ways and easier ways of doing stuff.

Ty.

Comment: It's not `$(window).load`, it's `$(document).ready`, or `$(function(){` for short. Then where is the `x` variable you're talking about? And the HTML code? I mean does the html tag actually have an ID?

Comment: Your Trial and error is looking more... error. at the moment.
Just use http://www.codecademy.com

Comment: (You want to edit your original post instead.)

Comment: yea sorry, i added it in the main post, and yes the html tag has an id

Comment: and i can't use document ready insted of window load for some reason because my loading screen with a gif on it and the fade in lag horribly with document ready